# How to implement UIViewControllerContextTransitioning compatible with interactive transitions

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I am on my way to create a custom navigation controller. Indeed, I would like to have a `UINavigationController` with a "content view" which is not necessarily the full screen, but which can be any view.

Since I also would like to use custom animations for transitions and interactive transitions, I will need to implement the protocol `UIViewControllerContextTransitioning`.

This protocol seems quite complicated and I am looking for good advice (from experienced users) and/or examples of such implementations.

> What are your advice and/or some resources for doing this?

The only resource I have found so far is the [github project](https://github.com/objcio/issue-12-custom-container-transitions) from the objc.io website. *But they are not dealing with interactive transitions.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [GREAT article with an associated github project](http://www.iosnomad.com/blog/2014/5/12/interactive-custom-container-view-controller-transitions). It is the continuation of [objc.io article](http://www.objc.io/issue-12/custom-container-view-controller-transitions.html).

It is so far (May 2015) and by far the best resource I have found on the subject.